# Inserting multiple rows into database

Tags: php, mysql

i have a `<?php include 'stats.php'; ?>` on every page on my site. in the `stats.php` file there is a SQL Insert query that inserts data into a table in my database.

for some reason when visiting just one page it inserts 4 rows into the database - there is only one SQL Command.

why would it be doing this... below is ALL the code on the `stats.php` file

```
<?php
   $activity_history_sql=
      "INSERT into user_activity_history (user_seq, user, timestamp, ip_address, user_request_uri, 
              user_script_filename, user_script_uri, user_script_url, user_script_name, user_php_self) 
       values ('".$_SESSION["domain.co.uk"]["sequence"]."', 
             '".$_SESSION["domain.co.uk"]["forename"].' '.$_SESSION["domain.co.uk"]["surname"]."', 
             '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', 
             '".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."', 
             '".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."', 
             '".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]."', 
             '".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"]."', 
             '".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_URL"]."', 
             '".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]."', 
             '".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."') ";
    $activity_history_rs=mysql_query($activity_history_sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps you're including files that include `stats.php`. Use `require_once` instead of `include`.

Comment: Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. See [_How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Not to mention that the `mysql_*` set of functions is deprecated.

Comment: Warning: mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.Please don't use `mysql` to develop new code.

Comment: Never post code and URL at the same time, especially not if it involves SQL code

Comment: im not sure i understand what you are talking about @IesusSonesson

Comment: You have an URL address in your session names, in order to make an attack with your provided code less likely you should not post an URL together with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - it seems to be working now. it may be that my cache hadn't refreshed properly. maybe it was still using the include rather than require_once

Answer (score 0):

Please use [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) when including stats.php.

> The require_once statement is identical to require except PHP will
>   check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include
>   (require) it again.

Comment: just changed all the pages to require_once but still the same issue

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are either (1) including the stats file more than once, (2) or refreshing your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try different method for include like require_once('stat.php');

... that might solve your issue...

This script doesnt seem faulty.

Comment: just changed all the pages to require_once but still the same issue

Comment: is there no way to do LIMIT 1 like you can in a SELECT Query

Comment: you posted full stat.php code but i m talking about the page in which you are including stat.php. that page might have looping function and page might reload several times before display and each time stat.php gets included and new record generate...

Comment: no this is not result generating script but you can use value check query which will check exact duplicate of record and skip if exist